# Add email field to comment drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to add an email field to submit new comment form in Drupal 6. I tried to use CCK, but I couldn't find a node type 'comment'.

Comment: That's because a comment isn't a node. Can you write custom modules?
See:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_comment/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to set the permission so that guests can write comments aswell (/admin/user/permissions#module-comment). After you did that, visit your website with another browser and make sure that you can add a comment.

The next step is to navigate to your node type settings (/admin/content/node-type/{your_node_type_name}), scroll down to the comment settings and set the radio box that says "guest comments" to "guests have to give their contact information" (I am not sure on the wording as I do not have the english version installed).

That should have worked: You should now have a required name and e-mail field plus an optional homepage field.

Answer (score 1):

Or for Drupal 7
- Select Structure -> Content types
- Find the node you want to change and press the edit link
- Select Comment Settings and select what you want from the drop-down

Answer (score 0):

Its actually content type -> content -> edit -> comment setting -> Anonymous commenting: -> Anonymous posters must leave their contact information

Answer (score 0):

Or for Drupal 7 - Select Structure -> Content types - Find the node you want to change and press the edit link - Select Comment Settings and select what you want from the drop-down